# Transfer data from one excel worksheet to another

Tags: python, openpyxl

[image: Input File]
[image: Output File]

I have an excel file in which all data is listed in rows, I need to take this data and list it in column A of individual worksheets in a newly created workbook. I cannot quite get the syntax correct. Please Assist

```
import openpyxl
import os
import time

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('IP-Results.xlsx') #load input file
sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('IP-Results-32708') #get sheet from input file

wbOutput = openpyxl.Workbook() #open a new workbook
wbOutput.remove_sheet(wbOutput.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet')) #remove initial worksheet named 'sheet'

for cell in sheet['A']: #iterate through firewall names in column A and make those the title of the sheets in new workbook
    value = cell.value
    wbOutput.create_sheet(title=cell.value)



for rowOfCellObjects in sheet.iter_rows():
    for data in rowOfCellObjects:
        if data.value != None:
            for worksheet in wbOutput.get_sheet_names():
                worksheet.cell(row=1, column=1).value = data


wbOutput.save("Decom-" + time.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")+ ".xlsx")
```

This code gives me the following error:

c:\Python35\Scripts>python decom.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "decom.py", line 21, in 
    ws=worksheet.active
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'active'

Comment: Can you please post `get_sheet_names()` function.

Comment: All of my code is there.

Comment: Note a problem, I just looked up the reference and replied with a possible solution.

Comment: Convert it to a `csv` then use python [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) to read, manipulate and write to a new csv. After you are done convert the new csv back to an excel workbook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`wbOutput.get_sheet_names()` returns a `list` of strings.

To reference a worksheet object use `wbOutput.worksheets[0]`

**Replace:**

`for worksheet in wbOutput.get_sheet_names():`

;with

`for worksheet in wbOutput.worksheets:`

Comment: So, my code now looks like: 
for rowOfCellObjects in sheet.iter_rows():
 for data in rowOfCellObjects:
  if data.value != None:
   for worksheet in wbOutput.worksheets:
    worksheet.cell(row=1, column=1).value = data

Comment: I get this error:   c:\Python35\Scripts>python decom.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "decom.py", line 21, in <module>
    worksheet.cell(row=1, column=1).value = data
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\cell\cell.py", line 294, in value

    self._bind_value(value)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\cell\cell.py", line 201, in _bind
_value
    raise ValueError("Cannot convert {0!r} to Excel".format(value))
ValueError: Cannot convert <Cell 'IP-Results-32708'.A1> to Excel

Comment: Hi, this looks like a new issue. Feel free to create a new thread, and set this one as answered, as I believe the original error is now gone, for others with similar errors in your original post.